# SQL Server Group by with WHEN clause

Tags: sql-server, group-by, case-when

Error in group by clause ::
I want make records unique in MS sql.here i have used 2-3 tables join and when clause.
it is more difficult to make it distinct by using group by clause it gives error like..

```
Error :::: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'GROUP'
```

---

```
select * from(
    SELECT TOP 5 m.pk_member_id,m.first_name+' '+m.middle_name+' '+m.last_name as "NAME", 
    m.gender AS "GENDER",
    datediff(Year,m.date_of_birth, getdate()) AS "AGE", 
    m.home_email AS "EMAIL", 
    m.business_phone AS "PHONE1", 
    m.cell_phone AS "PHONE2", 
    m.address+','+m.city+','+m.state+','+m.zip_code AS "ADDRESS", 
    paidamt = 
            CASE WHEN (moi.credit_card_amt!=null or moi.credit_card_amt > 0) THEN moi.credit_card_amt 
                 WHEN (moi.cheque_amt!=null or moi.cheque_amt > 0) THEN moi.cheque_amt 
                 WHEN (moi.debit_card_amt!=null or moi.debit_card_amt > 0) THEN moi.debit_card_amt 
                 WHEN (moi.cash_amt!=null or moi.cash_amt > 0) THEN moi.cash_amt 
            END, 
    mode = 
            CASE WHEN (moi.credit_card_amt!=null or moi.credit_card_amt > 0) THEN 'CREDIT CARD' 
                   WHEN (moi.cheque_amt!=null or moi.cheque_amt > 0) THEN 'CHEQUE' 
                   WHEN (moi.debit_card_amt!=null or moi.debit_card_amt > 0) THEN 'DEBIT CARD' 
                   WHEN (moi.cash_amt!=null or moi.cash_amt > 0) THEN 'CASH' 
            END, 
    m.registration_date as "JOINING DATE", 
    m.membership_expiry_date as "EXPIRY DATE", 
        services = 
                CASE WHEN m.pk_member_id=em.fk_member_id THEN 'EVENT' 
                         WHEN m.pk_member_id=dm.fk_member_id THEN 'DINING' 
                         WHEN m.pk_member_id=jm.fk_member_id THEN 'JF2' 
                END 
        FROM 
        Member m, 
        Member_Official_Info moi, 
        Event_Members em, 
        Dining_Members dm, 
        JF2_Members jm 
        WHERE 
        m.pk_member_id = moi.fk_member_id and 
        (m.pk_member_id = em.fk_member_id or m.pk_member_id = dm.fk_member_id or m.pk_member_id = jm.fk_member_id) and 
        YEAR(m.membership_expiry_date)=2008
        )
        GROUP BY 
        m.pk_member_id,m.first_name,m.middle_name, m.last_name,m.business_phone,m.cell_phone,m.address,m.city,\
        m.state,m.zip_code,m.gender,m.date_of_birth,m.home_email,m.registration_date, 
        m.membership_expiry_date,services,paidamt,mode;
```

Comment: Wow... nice query ... What is the error?

Comment: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'GROUP'

Comment: @ruchiworlds - Could you format this query please so we can see all of it without scrolling.

Comment: OK - couple of things: `!= null` isn't gonna work - this is T-SQL - not C#! Use ` IS NOT NULL` instead. Secondly: I would recommend to stop using that old-style JOIN syntax with just `table1, table2, table3 ......` and then a ton of WHERE clauses - use `INNER JOIN`, `LEFT OUTER JOIN` etc. and specify the JOIN condition on the JOIN itself - much clearer and more obvious what the h*** you're doing....

Comment: Also: **why** on earth do you need a GROUP BY in this huge query?? If you're getting duplicates, it's most likely because with your old-style JOIN syntax, you've produced a cartesian product since one of the JOIN conditions in the WHERE clause is gone / doesn't work..... Rewrite this mess to use the new ANSI JOIN's - and define the proper JOIN conditions! Then you shouldn't have any duplicates and thus no need for a GROUP BY (or if you still have duplicates, then you have other/ more serious problems with your fundamental design....)

Comment: i don't expect anything for it, but i went ahead and spelled out some of the ways to clean this up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just going into details on some of the issues with this:

change your from clause in the sub query to something like this:

```
from Member m
    inner join Member_Official_Info moi
        on m.pk_member_id=moi.fk_member_id
    left outer join Event_Members em
        on m.pk_member_id=em.fk_member_id
    left outer join Dining_Members dm
        on m.pk_member_id=em.fk_member_id
    left outer join JF2_Members jm
        on m.pk_member_id=em.fk_member_id
```

i'm guessing, like everyone else, that this'll probably remove the need for your group by clause

i'd also change your where clause in the subquery to this:

```
where m.membership_expiry_date>='1/1/2008'
    and m.membership_expiry_date<'1/1/2009'
```

Also, i'd change your paidamt and mode code to something like this:

```
case when coalesce(moi.credit_card_amt,0)>0 then moi.credit_card_amt
    when coalesce(moi.cheque_amt,0)>0 then moi.cheque_amt
    case when coalesce(moi.debit_card_amt,0)>0 then moi.debit_card_amt
    case when coalesce(moi.cash_amt,0)>0 then moi.cash_amt
```

Also, there's inconsistancy with your column aliasing.  in certain points your using Column Name=, or you're using  as "Column Name", or even as [Column Name].  This is rather confusing, so i'd pick one way to alias columns and stick with it.

Also, if fixing the joins works and doesn't require you to do the group by, then move everything out of the subquery cause there's no need for it

Answer (score 3):

Now I understand. 
You need to add the sub query name after `2008)`

```
select *
from(
  SELECT TOP 5
    m.pk_member_id,
    m.first_name+' '+m.middle_name+' '+m.last_name as "NAME",
    m.gender AS "GENDER",
    datediff(Year,m.date_of_birth, getdate()) AS "AGE",
    m.home_email AS "EMAIL",
    m.business_phone AS "PHONE Num 1",
    m.cell_phone AS "PHONE NUM 2",
    m.address+','+m.city+','+m.state+','+m.zip_code AS "MAILING ADDRESS",
    paidamt = CASE WHEN (moi.credit_card_amt!=null or moi.credit_card_amt > 0) THEN moi.credit_card_amt
                   WHEN (moi.cheque_amt!=null or moi.cheque_amt > 0) THEN moi.cheque_amt
                   WHEN (moi.debit_card_amt!=null or moi.debit_card_amt > 0) THEN moi.debit_card_amt
                   WHEN (moi.cash_amt!=null or moi.cash_amt > 0) THEN moi.cash_amt END,
    mode = CASE WHEN (moi.credit_card_amt!=null or moi.credit_card_amt > 0) THEN 'CREDIT CARD'
                WHEN (moi.cheque_amt!=null or moi.cheque_amt > 0) THEN 'CHEQUE'
                WHEN (moi.debit_card_amt!=null or moi.debit_card_amt > 0) THEN 'DEBIT CARD'
                WHEN (moi.cash_amt!=null or moi.cash_amt > 0) THEN 'CASH' END,
    m.registration_date as "JOINING DATE",
    m.membership_expiry_date as "EXPIRY DATE",
    services = CASE WHEN m.pk_member_id=em.fk_member_id THEN 'EVENT'
                      WHEN m.pk_member_id=dm.fk_member_id THEN 'DINING'
                      WHEN m.pk_member_id=jm.fk_member_id THEN 'JF2' END
  FROM
    Member m,
    Member_Official_Info moi,
    Event_Members em,
    Dining_Members dm,
    JF2_Members jm
  WHERE
    m.pk_member_id = moi.fk_member_id and
    (m.pk_member_id = em.fk_member_id or m.pk_member_id = dm.fk_member_id or m.pk_member_id = jm.fk_member_id) and
    YEAR(m.membership_expiry_date)=2008) as Q
group by
  m.pk_member_id,
  m.first_name,
  m.middle_name,
  m.last_name,
  m.business_phone,
  m.cell_phone,
  m.address,
  m.city,
  m.state,
  m.zip_code,
  m.gender,
  m.date_of_birth,
  m.home_email,
  m.registration_date,
  m.membership_expiry_date,
  services,paidamt,mode;
```

Comment: yup, was going thorugh it and that stood out to me.